# ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\phonebookController does not exist in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

I worked on localhost.there worked fine this laravel project. but when i uploaded it in live server it giving error with ReflectionException. Live address is

> http://www.nayeemriddhi.net/laravelphone/phonebook
>   ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

**PhonebookController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Http\Requests\PhonebookRequest;
use App\Phonebook;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PhonebookController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
            return view('phonebook');

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }


     public function getData()
    {
        return Phonebook::orderBy('name','ASC')-> get();
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(PhonebookRequest $request)
    {
        $pb = new Phonebook;

        $pb -> name = $request -> name;

        $pb -> phone = $request -> phone;

        $pb -> email = $request -> email;

        $pb -> save();

        return $pb;

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Phonebook  $phonebook
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Phonebook $phonebook)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Phonebook  $phonebook
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Phonebook $phonebook)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Phonebook  $phonebook
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(PhonebookRequest $request)
    {
        $pb = Phonebook::find($request->id);

        $pb -> name = $request -> name;

        $pb -> phone = $request -> phone;

        $pb -> email = $request -> email;

        $pb -> save();

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Phonebook  $phonebook
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Phonebook $phonebook)
    {
        Phonebook::where('id', $phonebook->id )-> delete();
    }
}
```

**Web.php** file code

```
<?php



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/phonebook/{name}', function () {

    return redirect('/');

})-> where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');


Route::resource('phonebook', 'phonebookController');

Route::post('getData', 'phonebookController@getData');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Route::resource('phonebook', 'phonebookController');
Route::post('getData', 'phonebookController@getData');
```

To:

```
Route::post('getData', 'PhonebookController@getData');
Route::resource('phonebook', 'PhonebookController');
```

Also, run `php artisan route:clear` to clear routes cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('phonebook', 'PhonebookController');

Route::post('getData', 'PhonebookController@getData');
```

It is due to name conflict. Notice that your controller name and name used in route file.

May be you are using windows os in your local machine which ignores capitalization, But in linux server it strictly checks.

Comment: `PhonebookController !== phonebookController`